# Cakephp name column override

Tags: php, cakephp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List view for belongs to relation in cake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891009/list-view-for-belongs-to-relation-in-cake)

I have table that has hasMany and belongTo relations. So users table belongs to communes and communes has many users.

Users table has commune_id column and I believe as per cake default you need to have 'name' column in communes table however if you do not want to change this to name. How do you override this and define another column name to act as name so it automatically generates dropdown box in the Users view?

Comment: Hi Charles, this one is actually a different question as it is asking for name column and the other one is asking about primary key which is id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i always thought this is one of the best documented parts of the cookbook.
I can only wonder...

$this->displayField = 'your_custom_name';

Comment: and `$displayField = 'blah';` in the model if you always want to use that field as a displayField.